# function doesn't return long long int

Tags: c

I don't know why my function doesn't give the correct result. I suspect that it doesn't return the right type (unsigned long long int), but it return an int instead.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// compile with:
//         gcc prog_long_long.c -o prog_long_long.exe
// run with:
//         prog_long_long

unsigned long long int dec2bin(unsigned long long int);

int main() {
    unsigned long long int d, result;

    printf("Enter an Integer\n");

    scanf("%llu", &d);

    result = dec2bin(d);

    printf("The number in binary is %llu\n", result);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

unsigned long long int dec2bin(unsigned long long int n) {
    unsigned long long int rem;
    unsigned long long int bin = 0;
    int i = 1;
    while (n != 0) {
        rem = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        bin = bin + (rem * i);
        i = i * 10;
    }
    return bin;
}
```

Here is the output of the result with different input values:

```
C:\Users\desktop\Desktop\gcc prog_long_long.c -o prog_long_long.exe

C:\Users\desktop\Desktop\prog_long_long
Enter an Integer
1023
The number in binary is 1111111111
The number in octal is 1777

C:\Users\desktop\Desktop\prog_long_long
Enter an Integer
1024
The number in binary is 1410065408
The number in octal is 2994
```

Comment: What number are you typing in response to the prompt?  What number are you getting back for it?

Comment: There is no way that a function can return something of a different type than the one you specify in the definition.

Comment: Why is `i` suddenly declared as an `int` inside your `dec2bin`, when everything else is `unsigned long long`? That's probably the variable that overflows and leads to incorrect result, not your completely unfounded suspicion about the function "returning an `int`".

Comment: `i` is `int` and can overflow quickly.

Comment: And you're not really converting to binary, you're "converting" to a different decimal number.

Comment: Exactly. A separate question is: what on earth are you trying to do in this function? You are generating a number whose decimal representation would "look like" a binary representation. Is that what you really wanted to do? What would be the point of such conversion?

Comment: Please **edit** your post with the **text** of the output, not a screen shot.  Screen snapshots are generally for GUI or graphics outputs.

Comment: Is the C++ tag correct?  Your file has ".c" extension.  Your header files use the C standard libraries.  Your input and output use C language functions.  Why is this code C++? (Note: C and C++ are different languages.)

Comment: Since you tagged this as C++, I recommend you convert the variable to a binary text format using `std::string`.

Comment: compile with `-pedantic` and see if it gives you any warnings. Likely there is a narrowing conversion warning in the loop.

Comment: Posting pictures of text attracts down-votes,  Suggest editing that data into the post as text.

Comment: No need from parenthesis here `bin = bin+(rem*i);`

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, the OP uses plain C.

Comment: @AnT

That was the right answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a number to binary this way, decimal and binary are external representations of the same number. You should convert the number as a C string, computing one binary digit at a time, from right to left.

Here is how it works for 64-bit long long ints:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *dec2bin(char *dest, unsigned long long int n);

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long int d;
    char buf[65], *result;

    printf("Enter an Integer\n");

    if (scanf("%llu", &d) == 1) {
        result = dec2bin(buf, d);
        printf("The number in binary is %s\n", result);
    }

    //system("pause");

    return 0;
}

char *dec2bin(char *dest, unsigned long long int n) {
    char buf[65];
    char *p = buf + sizeof(buf);

    *--p = '\0';
    while (n > 1) {
        *--p = (char)('0' + (n % 2));
        n = n / 2;
    }
    *--p = (char)('0' + n);
    return strcpy(dest, p);
}
```

Comment: That is a sound advice, but not an answer to the question. And why do you talk about string and then use char*? And why do you declare result out of the scope of your condition? That's pretty much C style. Just like the pointer arithmetics and the *--p = ... stuff. Would focus on readability instead.

Comment: @Aziuth: the question was tagged both C and C++. The OP used plain C, I answered with C code. I am sure there are C++ solutions that fit on a single line with a dozen or more `:`.

Comment: Ah k, didn't see the double tags, my bad.